# BO WEBI : Extracting in two different columns different values from the same dimension

Tags: reporting, business-objects

Friends,

I've been struggling with this report for some days trying to figure it out by myself, but I'm not going anywhere. As you can see below, the point is to get a report based on two different queries (QUERY1 and QUERY2) with a common dimension Q1F1 & Q2F1. I'd like to get two separate columns in the report matching the KEYS (actually a 9 digits string), Q1FA (a 20 digits string) and Q2F1(20 digits string).

Any idea how to deal with this situation please? Thanks a million!

[image]

Comment: In REPORT, how does A0 correlate to A2?

Comment: They have the same Key on query2. and it has Q2F3=1. does that help? THANKS

Comment: I don't think you're going to be able to achieve that result without somehow getting the KEY field into QUERY1.

Comment: Thanks Joe. I'll be keeping hope for some tricky detail variables!

Comment: Would be a nifty trick :)  the problem is that you're attempting a three-way join: from QUERY1 to QUERY2 to get the Keys for Q1F1, then again to QUERY2 to associate all Q1F1 values to each Q2F2.  It would be much easier to do if you had the Key values in QUERY1.

Comment: I made it finally! I'll post that in the answer later :). Thnx

Comment: Please do - I'm curious to see how you did it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I figured this out.

Without using Query 1, and using only Query 2.

Create a detail variable on Q2F1 with associate dimention Q2F2 (the keys) as follows:

> det_REPF1 = [Q2F1] where ([Q2F3]=1)
>
> Create a detail variable on Q2F1 with the same associate dimention
>   Q2F2 (the keys) as follows: det_REPF2 = [Q2F1] where ([Q2F3]=0)
>
> In the Report the column are as follows:
>
> Col1 = Q2F2 dimension from Query 2. Col2 = Min(det_REPF2)  'This is
>   outputing multivalues I take the min Col3 = det_REPF1

And you're done.
Hope this helps.